# docker-compose gives error "ImportError: No module named ssl_match_hostname" when run as normal user

Tags: python, docker, pip, docker-compose

I've installed docker-compose with 'pip2.7 install docker-compose" but when I try to run it as 'normal' user I get the following error message:

```
mike@hugin:~/Tobedeleted$ docker-compose  -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/errors.py", line 10, in <module>
    from docker.errors import APIError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .api import APIClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .client import APIClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .build import BuildApiMixin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .build import tar, exclude_paths
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .utils import create_archive
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .. import tls
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/tls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .transport import SSLAdapter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/transport/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ssladapter import SSLAdapter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/transport/ssladapter.py", line 21, in <module>
    from backports.ssl_match_hostname import match_hostname
ImportError: No module named ssl_match_hostname
```

This user is part of the docker group and can run 'docker ps' etc without any issue.

If I try to run 'sudo docker-compose -v' I get the same error.

However, if I run 'sudo su -' first and then issue 'docker-compose -v' I get the expected output.

```
root@hugin:~# docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
```

I've tried 'pip uninstall' for various, and all, parts of docker-compose, ssl_match_hostname and then reinstall but nothing seems to resolve it.

I'm now thoroughly stuck - any ideas out there?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you have to reinstall docker-compose using this command:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

it worked for me

Comment: I also had to 1/ uninstall docker-compose first and 2/run ```sudo rm /home/myName/.local/bin/docker-compose``` (as it conflicted in my path name)
And for a up-to-date install (and uninstall) instructions see here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Comment: see latest release at   https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

Comment: @SofienM it is recommended to get the installation command from 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/ and currently the latest version is 1.29.2

Comment: Permanent latest version URL: `https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-\`uname -s\`-\`uname -m\``

Answer (score 6):

you should check if docker-compose exist, is installed and running:

```
$ whereis docker-compose
$ docker-compose --version
```

check if exist symbolic link `pip -> pip2.7` or `pip -> pip3.6` by running:

```
$ sudo pip install docker-compose
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me after updating to `Python 3.10`.
I fixed it by reinstalling `docker-compose` with:

`pip install docker-compose`

Note: running `yay -S docker-compose` on Manjaro didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Docker Compose now runs as a Docker plugin. I recommend using:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin
```

And then use `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`

Answer (score 1):

```
docker compose pull
```

if you have docker 24

Answer (score -1):

Check the permission on the remote host where the ansible jobs are getting executed.

Make sure the "other" users have the execute permission of the module packages.

```
sudo chmod -R  o=rx /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly check if you have the docker sock file under /var/run/.

```
# ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
# docker info
```

If the file doesn't exist, then restart the docker service. If it still doesn't exist, restart the node and see if you have the file.

Answer (score -3):

**Also worked for me.**

**Issue**
root@ashish:/DOCKER#  docker-compose -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 5, in 
    from compose.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'

**Solution**

curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

After executed above command,  Output should be look like given below.

root@ashish:/DOCKER# docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb

Thanks
Ashish Jha